# ¿Cómo guardar cada elemento de una lista en formato csv?

Tags: r

¡Hola!

Quisiera saber cómo podría guardar una lista que contiene 159 data frames en formato CSV.

He intentado con la función `lapply` , en el siguiente código que me recomendaron en una respuesta anterior `lapply(X=Sitios2010, FUN= function(x){write.csv(x, file = paste0(as.character(x$Sites), '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)})` pero me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
$ 03 SOACHA - LADRILLERA SANTAFE
NULL

$05 SIBATE- LOS SAUCES
NULL
```

Y así para cada uno de los data frames.

¡Muchas Gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema que bien podría pasar por un error tipográfico pero en realidad es un tema de concepto que es importante aclarar. cuando haces esto:

```
lapply(X=Sitios2010, 
       FUN= function(x){write.csv(x, 
                                  file = paste0(as.character(x$Sites), '.csv'), 
                                  row.names = FALSE)
                        })
```

Estas haciendo un ciclo implícito por una lista `Sitios2010`, donde cada elemento , entiendo, es un `data.frame` correspondiente a cada `Sites` (en la función es el parámetro `x`), y claro estás queriendo construir los nombres del `csv` usando esta variable, pero el problema es que no tienes una sola, sino múltiples ocurrencias de la misma por cada una de las filas del `data.frame`, por lo que el `paste` termina siendo una concatenación de estos nombres. Esto lo resuelves, obteniendo un solo elemento de dicha columna, por ejemplo `x$Sites[1]`:

```
lapply(X=Sitios2010, 
       FUN= function(x){write.csv(x, 
                                  file = paste0(as.character(x$Sites[1]), '.csv'), 
                                  row.names = FALSE)
                        })
```

El otro problema, es que los sistemas operativos imponen limitaciones a los nombres de archivo y es probable que tal vez los valores de `Sites` no sea compatible, en cuyo caso deberías "sanitizar" el nombre quitando los caracteres que no sean consistentes con el SO.

Comment: ¡Hola Patricio! Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. He intentado con el código que me has recomendado, y me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Creo que el problema principal es que tengo muchos sitios con tilde y ñ que el programa no toma, he intentado cambiarlo a UTF-8 pero no lo he lografo, o no he entendido bien cómo podría hacerlo. ¿Me podrías recomendar cómo "sanitizar" los nombres?

Comment: Pareciera que los nombres tienen un código numérico, si ese dato lo tienes en una columna, seguramente te convenga usarlo en vez de `Sites`. Sino podrías quitar todos lo que no sean los primeros dos números, así `gsub('([0-9]+) .*', '\\1', x$Sites[1])`. Hay también una rutina `path_sanitize()` en el paquete `fs`.

Comment: De todas formas Laura, lo que has mostrado como error no parece tal, sino el resultado de la ejecución de `lapply`, ¿has revisado en la carpeta si se han generado los archivos?

Comment: ¡Hola Patricio! Ya pude resolver el problema de las tildes y las ñs, aún así, cuando intento aplicar el código me sigue saliendo el mismo error :( . Revisé, y me guarda el csv sólo con uno de los sitios. No sé qué podría hacer.

Comment: ¿que significa? ¿se te generan los archivos pero vacíos? ¿no se genera ninguno? ¿Hay efectivamente datos para cada sitio?

Comment: Me genera sólo un archivo CSV con uno sólo de los lugares, de 200 lugares. En la lista, aparecen todos los lugares con datos, pero al tratar de guardarlo, me genera un único archivo CSV.